# I can't populate data using MongoDB and Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, populate

these are the two models that I have.

user.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
  },
  passwordHashed: {
    type: String,
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
  },
  student: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Student" }],
});

const Users = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = Users;
```

student.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
  },
});

const Students = mongoose.model("Student", studentSchema);

module.exports = Students;
```

My problem is I want to populate the data to user.js but when I am running this code:

```
const user = await Users.find().populate('student')
console.log(user)
```

It just returns me an empty array of the student. How can I fix this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For any type population/join I all time use mongodb $lookup. 
It's much powerful, flexible and covenant than using population.

According your userSchema, most probably you have store the _id of student document on userSchema's student array. 
If I'm correct then you can follow this way:

```
await Users.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "students",
      "localField": "student",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "studentList"
    }
  }
])
```

Though your student field of userSchema is objectId, then you don't further need to do anything, else you have to convert your localField as  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(student)

here is an example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/fuw9Drld9M-